# What is the flag on Shinzo Abe's suit?

Tags: japan, flags

[image: Here] and [image: here] are random a photos from a performance of Prime Minister of Japan Shinzo Abe. The emblem number 1, as I understand, is the Imperial Seal. But I couldn't find any information about the emblem number 2. Can you say, what it is?

Comment: This has already been answered on another site in the SE network: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15560/what-is-this-blue-badge-that-prime-minister-shinzo-abe-likes-to-wear

Comment: I think this is a good question and an interesting question, but I'm closing it because it is answered on [politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/15563).